# Dynamically create eval condition in python

Tags: python

I've got a list with n elements, let's say there are 3 for example:

```
[Condition1, Condition2, Condition3]
```

I want to build up a string which looks like this, in the order that appears in the list (that order is vital!):

```
eval(Condition1).otherwise(eval(Condition2).otherwise(eval(Condition3)))
```

So if only the first 2 elements exist in the list in that order, then I would get this:

```
eval(Condition1).otherwise(eval(Condition2))
```

And similarly if only the first element is in the list, then I want this:

```
eval(Condition1)
```

Just for context, Condition1, Condition2 and Condition3 are already set prior to this, and I'm aiming to eval all of them in one statement.  Example code is below, actual data is a lot more complicated of course, the only thing I'm struggling with is how to build the final EVAL_ALL statement

```
Condition1 = "when(col('YearMonths') < 202306, 'SMALL')"
Condition2 = "when(col('YearMonths') > 202306, 'BIG')"

EVAL_ALL = "eval(Condition2).otherwise(eval(Condition1).otherwise('Nothing'))"

display(df.select(col('YearMonths'), eval(EVAL_ALL)))
```

Comment: Already feeling a bit jittery at the sight of `eval` here. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Could you add more details? Specifically, what are `Condition1`..`3` and do you want to build up a string or evaluate an expression?

Comment: If a list is like `[a]` you can only retrieve the object referenced by variable `a` from the list but not the name `'a'` itself (unless it is stored in the object referenced by `a`).

Comment: I don't know what library you are using, but you likely don't need to store the conditions as strings in the first place. `conditions = [when(col('YearMonths') < 202306, 'SMALL'), when(...), when(...)]`. A loop similar to that shown in my answer can then be used to construct the final argument to be passed to `df.select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating this as *strictly* a string-building exercise (the use of `eval` is suspect), you want to process the list in reverse order. For example, something like

```
conditions = reversed(["Condition1", "Condition2", "Condition3"])

result = f'eval({next(conditions)})'
for c in conditions:
    result = f'eval({c}).otherwise({result})'
```